# Uniform Convergence of a certain sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I have the sequence $$f_n(x)=\log \left(\Pi_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{x^k+1}{x^k}\right)^k\right)$$ and I have to study the uniform convergence.

Equivalently we have $$f_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{x^k} \;\log \left(1+\frac{1}{x^k}\right)^{x^k}$$

Now the original request tranforms in studying the uniform convergence of the series $$\sum_k \frac{k}{x^k} \;\log \left(1+\frac{1}{x^k}\right)^{x^k}$$

The first thing I want to do is verifying the necessary condition: necessary condition for the series to converge is that $$\lim_k \frac{k}{x^k} \;\log \left(1+\frac{1}{x^k}\right)^{x^k}=0$$

If we take any $x$ in $(-\infty,-1) \cup(1,+\infty)$ the above equality holds. (If I have done the limit correctly).

Now I want to try with the **ratio test**: 
$$\lim_k \; \left|\frac{(k+1)\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x^{k+1}}\right)}{k\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x^k}\right)}\right|=\frac{1}{|x|}$$ 
which assures convergence if $x\in (-\infty,-1) \cup(1,+\infty)$. (If I have done the limit correctly).

**For** the uniform convergence I have to study 
$$\sup \left| \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty} k\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x^k}\right)-\sum_{k=1}^{n} k\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x^k}\right)\right|=\sup \left| \sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty} k\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x^k}\right)\right|$$ with $x\in I=(-\infty,-1) \cup(1,+\infty)$.

I noticed that this sup is greater than $(n+1)\log2$ and thus I have **not** uniform convergence in $I$.

> Is my reasoning correct till here? How can I find the subset of $I$ in which I have uniform convergence?

Comment: When $n\equiv 1 \pmod 4$, I don't think $f_n$ is defined for $x\in[-1,0]$. The argument of the logarithm would be $\leqslant 0$.

Comment: Why is the sup greater than $(n+1)\log 2$?

Comment: That sup is greater than the first summand (since for $x>1$ all the summands are positive), which is $(n+1)\log(1+\frac{1}{x^{n+1}})$ and as $x$ approaches $1$ we have $(n+1)\log2$. Is it correct?

Comment: I guess it is correct.
We can confidently say that

\begin{align}
\sup_{x\in I}\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty} k\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x^k}\right)\right|
&\geqslant
\sup_{x\in (1,+\infty)}\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty} k\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x^k}\right)\right|
\\&=
\sup_{x\in (1,+\infty)}\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty} k\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x^k}\right)
\\&\geqslant
\sup_{x\in (1,+\infty)} (n+1)\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x^{n+1}}\right)
\end{align}

*(continues)*

Comment: *(continued)* In other words,

$$\sup_{x\in I}\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty} k\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x^k}\right)\right|
\geqslant
(n+1)\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x^{n+1}}\right)$$

for every $x>1$.
By continuity of the RHS we must then have $\sup_{x\in I}\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty} k\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x^k}\right)\right| \geqslant (n+1)\log(2)$. This is way simpler than my answer and shows that whenever the domain contains $1$ as an accumulation point, the $f_n$ fail to converge uniformly.

Answer (score 1):

When $x\in[-1,0]$ the sequence $f_n(x)$ is ill defined.
When $x\in(0,1]$, the general term of the series becomes unbounded as $k\to\infty$.

It follows that one need consider only $x\in I$.
You've already shown pointwise convergence in $I$.

Now, for uniform convergence we need to show that given $\epsilon>0$ we can find $n\in\Bbb N$ such that for every $x\in I$

$$\left| \sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty} k\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x^k}\right)\right| < \epsilon.$$

In other words, we can make the difference $|f_n(x) - f(x)|$ as small as desired by taking $n$ large enough **uniformly** on $x$.

---

For $z > -1$ we have

$$\log\left(1+z\right) \geqslant\frac{z}{1+z}$$

It follows that

\begin{align}
\sup_{x\in I}\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty} k\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x^k}\right)\right|
&\geqslant
\sup_{x\in (1,+\infty)}\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty} k\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x^k}\right)\right|
\\&=
\sup_{x\in (1,+\infty)}\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty} k\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x^k}\right)
\\&\geqslant
\sup_{x\in (1,+\infty)}\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty} k\,\,\frac{x^{-k}}{1+x^{-k}}
\\&=
\sup_{x\in (1,+\infty)}\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty} \frac k {x^k + 1}
\\&\geqslant
\sup_{x\in (1,+\infty)}\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty} \frac k {2x^k}
\\&=
\sup_{x\in (1,+\infty)}\frac{(n+1)x-n}{2x^{n}{(x-1)}^2}
\end{align}

As $x$ approaches $1$, we see that the sup is unbounded.
Therefore, the $f_n$ fail to converge uniformly on $(1,+\infty)$.

---

On the other hand, for $z > -1$ we have

$$\log\left(1+z\right) \leqslant z.$$

Let $a>1$ and consider.

\begin{align}
\sup_{x\in [a,+\infty)}\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty} k\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x^k}\right)\right|
&=
\sup_{x\in [a,+\infty)}\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty} k\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x^k}\right)
\\&\leqslant
\sup_{x\in [a,+\infty)}\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty} \frac k {x^k}
\\&=
\sup_{x\in [a,+\infty)}\frac{(n+1)x-n}{x^n(x-1)^2}
\end{align}

From the derivative of $g_n(x) = \frac{(n+1)x-n}{x^n(x-1)^2}$ being always negative and the fact that $\lim_{x\to\infty}g_n(x) = 0$, we conclude that

$$\sup_{x\in [a,+\infty)}\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty} k\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x^k}\right)\right|\leqslant g_n(a).$$

Moreover, it's easy to see that $\lim_{n\to\infty}g_n(a) = 0$, so that the $f_n$ converge uniformly on $[a,+\infty)$.

---

The case for $x\in(-\infty,1)$ can be handled similarly, but requires some care dealing with absolute values.
Do you think you can take it from here?

Comment: Thank-you very much for your beautiful answer :)  I am carefully checking all the steps. At the moment I have some trouble with showing that the derivative of $g_n(x)$ is always negative. P.S. Why do you also need that $\lim_{x\to \infty}g_n(x)=0$ to conclude that $$\sup_{x\in [a,+\infty)}\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty} k\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x^k}\right)\right|\leqslant g_n(a).$$? It isn't enought that its derivative is always negative?

Comment: You don't need it actually. All you need to show to be honest is that the $\sup$ on $[a,+\infty)$ goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty$. I tried to find an argument using the boundedness of each $g_n$ $($which follows from $\lim_{x\to\infty} g_n(x) = 0)$, which would make the derivative unnecessary, but I ended up going the derivative route and I guess I left $\lim_{x\to\infty} g_n(x) = 0$ as an artifact of my previous attempts.